# Accessing JSON by using a constant

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON looks as following:

```
{
    flight_number: 1,
    mission_name: "FalconSat",
    rocket: {
        rocket_id: "falcon1",
        rocket_name: "Falcon 1",
        rocket_type: "Merlin A",
        first_stage: {
            cores: [
                {
                    core_serial: "Merlin1A",
                    flight: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        fairings: {
            reused: false,
            recovery_attempt: false,
            recovered: false,
            ship: null
        }
    },
    links: {
        video_link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a_00nJ_Y88",
        flickr_images: [ ]
    },
    details: "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle"
}
```

To access the video link, I want to use a constant and I've been trying to use:

```
const links = "links";
const video1 = links + ".video_link";        // this doesn't work 
const video2 = "links.video_link";           // this doesn't work
const det = "details";

getVideoURL(something) {
    console.log(something.video1);           // undefined
    console.log(something.links.video_link); // this works
    console.log(something.det);              // this works

    return something.video2;
}

getDetails(something) {
    return something.det;                    // this works
}

// the jsonObject is retrieved by an async function, i just simplified it. I hope this makes sense.
const jsonObject = await axios("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches");

let url = getVideoURL(jsonObject);
let det = getDetails(something);

console.log(url)                             // undefined
console.log(det)                             // prints out details.
```

Is there a way I can get the video URL like how I've done it with `getDetails` by using `return something.video1` or `return something.video2`?

Comment: the `jsonObject` is retrieved by an `async` function, i just simplified it. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead of a string, and then you can use `reduce` to iterate over each key in the array, accessing the appropriate nested property value, passing in the entire object as the initial value of the accumulator `a`:

```js
const obj = {flight_number:1,mission_name:"FalconSat",rocket:{rocket_id:"falcon1",rocket_name:"Falcon 1",rocket_type:"Merlin A",first_stage:{cores:[{core_serial:"Merlin1A",flight:1}]},fairings:{reused:!1,recovery_attempt:!1,recovered:!1,ship:null}},links:{video_link:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a_00nJ_Y88",flickr_images:[]},details:"Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle"};

const getVideoURL = obj => path.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);

const path = ['links', 'video_link'];
const url = getVideoURL(obj);
console.log(url);
```

Alternatively, if you *wanted* to use a string, you would have to split on `.`s first:

```
const pathString = "links.video_link";
const getVideoURL = obj => pathString
  .split('.')
  .reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm rather new to javascript and I'm trying to understand what's happening in your second example at `.reduce`. `a` is the accumulator and `prop` is the iteration of the array, but what happens in `a[prop, obj`?

Comment: In a `reduce`, the callback is performed using two arguments, the result of the previous operation (variable name `a` in this case, the accumulator) and the current item being iterated over. On the first iteration, there's no previous result, so the initial value is used (the second argument passed to `.reduce`, the `obj`). So, first iteration: `a[prop]` resolves to `obj['links']`, which becomes the next accumulator. Second iteration: `a[prop]` resolves to `obj['links']['video_link']`. That exhausts the array, so the result of `obj['links']['video_link']` is returned

Comment: Awesome, excellently explained so even a noob like me understood it :) thanks!